# Jquery как запомнить изначальную высоту ul?

Tags: jquery

Есть код

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Нужно определить высоту начальную и при клике её устанавливать. 
Сейчас код такой

```
height = "тут должна быть изначальная высота элемента";
    $('ul > li > ul').css('height','0px');    
    $('ul > li').click(function() {       
            $(this).children('ul').animate().css('height',height);
        });
```

как можно записать высоту элементов не создавая разных переменных?

Comment: `height = $('ul > li > ul').css('height')`

Comment: но li может быть сколько угодно

Comment: ну и что? :-)  сохраняйте значение для верхнего уровня например

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно хранить значение начальной высоты элемента в его data-атрибуте: https://jsfiddle.net/vkhLeL6m/

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('ul ul').each(function(){
        var $el = $(this),
            height = $el.height();
        $el.data('height', height);
        $el.height(0);
    });
    $('ul>li').click(function(){
        var $ul = $(this).children('ul');
        $ul.animate({
            'height':$ul.data('height')
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Например вот так

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var height = $('ul > li > ul').height();
 $('ul > li > ul').height(0);
 $('ul > li').click(function() {       
  $(this).children('ul').animate({
    height: height
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: Только не понятно для чего тебе анимировать высоту, если ты хочешь сделать выпадающий анимированый список то лучше использовать slideUp и slideDown

Comment: он криво работает, ваш пример только для одного li работать будет

Comment: ты хочешь сделать выпадающий список ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5ow2zc0L/1/ на вот наверное то что тебе нужно